# Adding a countdown timer to giveaway command discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I was trying to create a discord bot with giveaway command which updates time left every 1-2 mins in giveaway embed . I have been trying it since 3 days but wasn't able to find a solution. I managed to make it update seconds, but if I specify time more than 1m i.e. 60 seconds it automatically converts it to seconds and starts giveaway with time left in just seconds . I want it to keep time in given unit and update time in --days, --hours, --minutes, --seconds left.

Here are a few images what I mean:

[what it currently do:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2U2Y.png)

[what I want it to do:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcHCb.png)

Its just Ends In Or Time remaining what i want to be changed!

My current code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import random
import datetime









TOKEN = ""
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">", case_sensitive=False)
bot.remove_command("help")










@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.dnd,
                              activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=">help"))
    print("Bot is online!")





@bot.command()
@commands.bot_has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def gwstart(ctx):

    giveaway_questions = ['Which channel will i host the giveaway in?', 'What is the prize?', 'How long should the giveaway run for? (in seconds)']
    giveaway_answers = []

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    for question in giveaway_questions:
        await ctx.send(question)
        try:
            message = await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=30.0, check= check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send('You didn\'t answer in time. Please try again and be sure to send your answer within 30 seconds of the question.')
            return
        else:
            giveaway_answers.append(message.content)


    try:
        c_id=int(giveaway_answers[0][2:-1])
    except:
        await ctx.send(f'You failed to mention the channel correctly. Please do it like this: {ctx.channel.mention}')
        return


    channel= bot.get_channel(c_id)
    prize = str(giveaway_answers[1])
    time = int(giveaway_answers[2])

    await ctx.send(f'The giveaway for {prize} will begin shortly.\nPlease direct your attention to {channel.mention},This giveaway will end in {time} seconds.')

    e = discord.Embed(color=0x000000, timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    e.set_author(name= f'GIVEAWAY!!', icon_url = 'https://i.imgur.com/DDric14.png')
    e.add_field(name = f'**Prize:-__{prize}__**!!', value = f'**Giveaway Time Remaining:-__{round(time/60, 2)}__Miniutes!**\n **HOSTED BY:-__{ctx.author.mention}__**\n `React with "" to participate in this giveaway!` ', inline=False)
    e.set_footer(text='\u200b')
    my_message = await channel.send(embed=e)


    await my_message.add_reaction("")
    await  asyncio.sleep(time)

    new_message=await channel.fetch_message(my_message.id)

    users = await new_message.reactions[0].users().flatten()
    users.pop(users.index(bot.user))
    winner = random.choice(users)

    ee=discord.Embed(color=0x000000, timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    ee.set_author(name=f'THE GIVEAWAY HAS ENDED!', icon_url='https://i.imgur.com/DDric14.png')
    ee.add_field(name = f' Prize: {prize}', value = f' **Winner**: {winner.mention}\n  **Number of Entrants**: {len(users)}', inline = False)
    ee.set_footer(text='\u200b')
    await channel.send(embed=ee)
    await channel.send(f"***__{winner.mention}__ Please claim your reward(s) from the host***")












bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Any help is highly appreciated!  And I m sorry if I wasn't able to make you understand my problem.

Comment: Is using asyncio sleep fine? Or, do you expect giveaways to last longer amounts of time, such as several weeks, persistent across bot restarts?

Answer (score 0):

Just convert whichever unit they put in to seconds. If they say “10 minutes”. Do `asyncio.sleep(time * 60)`. You can ask them to specify the time unit to help pick what you want to multiply time by. Hope this helps :D